# How can I vectorize these loops in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, vectorization

```
function[Y] = busadmittance(z)
ne = z(:,1); nt = z(:,2); r = z(:,3); x = z(:,4); lines = length(ne);   
buses = max(max(ne), max(nt));                         
Z = r + 1j*x;                            
y = ones(length(Z),1)./Z;                            
Y = zeros(buses,buses);
```

How can I vectorize below 'for' loops, that follows the above code?

```
for k = 1:buses                         
    for l = 1:lines
        if ne(l) == k || nt(l) == k
        Y(k,k) = Y(k,k)+ y(l);
        end
    end
end

for k = 1:lines                          
    if ne(k)>0 && nt(k) > 0 
        Y(ne(k),nt(k)) = -y(k);
        Y(nt(k),ne(k)) = -y(k);
    end
end
```

are there any additional code enhancements apart from preallocation and vectorization, that can greatly affect the performance? (forget gpu, cluster)

Answer (score 0):

The first nested loop can be vectorized as:

```
Y(1:size(Y,1)+1:end) = (bsxfun(@eq, ne.' , 1:buses) | bsxfun(@eq, nt.' , 1:buses)) * y;
```

That In Octave or Matlab R2016b it can be writen as:

```
Y(1:size(Y,1)+1:end) = (ne.' == 1:buses | nt.' == 1:buses) * y;
```

Vectorization of the second nested loop :

```
k1= k(ne>0 & nt > 0 );
idx = accumarray([ne(k1),nt(k1)],1,size(Y),@any);
Y(idx) = -y(k1);
Y(idx.') = -y(k1);
```

or

```
k1= k(ne>0 & nt > 0 );
idx1 = sub2ind(size(Y),ne(k1),nt(k1));
idx2 = sub2ind(size(Y),nt(k1),ne(k1));
Y(idx1)=-y(k1);
Y(idx2)=-y(k1);
```